# Calculate area of “hand-drawn” polygon

Tags: coordinate-systems, area, polygons

I have a series of coordinates that represent a hand-drawn polygon. At the intersection, the lines slightly "overshoot," e.g.:

```
x   y
-24 20
-23 20
20  23
23  -23
-22 -23
-23 23
-24 24
```

The actual file has hundreds of coordinates. I need to calculate the area of the polygon. The traditional approach (http://www.mathsisfun.com/geometry/area-irregular-polygons.html) is inaccurate because of the overshoot. I need to either find a way to calculate the area and ignore the overshoot or crop the data so that it does not overshoot. Thank you!

Comment: You give a list of points. What are the overshooting lines, and how is the polygon defined that you have in mind?

Comment: What does *overshoot* mean?

Comment: Basically if you graph the coordinates you see a polygon with the lines over extending at the point in which the meet (top left). I tried to post a picture but I don't have enough reputation points to do it

Answer (score 1):

If the vertices of the polygon have coordinates $(x_1,y_1),\dots,(x_n,y_n)$, then the area of the polygon is
$$
{1 \over 2} 
\Big | 
\sum_{i=1}^{n} \det\begin{pmatrix} x_i & x_{i+1} \\ y_i & y_{i+1} \end{pmatrix} \Big |
$$
where
$x_{n+1}=x_1$ and 
$y_{n+1}=y_1$.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shoelace_formula.

Comment: This is what I tried originally, but it does not come up with an accurate answer because some of the coordinates are "outside" of the polygon

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Monte-Carlo method of finding an approximate area. This involves creating a reference area and randomly throwing points all over the figure. You would then count how many points land inside the figure and how many points there are in total, divide them respectively, and then multiply by the reference area. Ergo, if you're trying to find the area of some figure $S$ with reference area $T$, $$A_{est} = \frac{\text{total }(x,y) \in S}{\text{total points used}}\times T.$$

Here are a few worked examples: http://www.mathdemos.org/mathdemos/MCArea/MCArea.html

This unfortunately only gives an approximation, but the approximation is pretty decent most of the time. The advantage is that it's quick and easy because YOU choose what $T$ can be. Obviously, $T$ can be a square/rectable since area of a rectangle with length $l$ and width $w$ is $A_{rect} = lw$.

Comment: This is an interesting approach. The error in estimation using the regular "shoelace approach" tends to be very small since there are hundreds of coordinate pairs and the ones outside the polygon are only a few units off.  I don't know whether this method would be a better estimate or not. I might just have to live with the slight error.